# DJI Ronin RS 2: Obtain angle information faster than 5 Hz

Tags: dji-sdk

Working with the DJI Ronin RS 2, I would like to ask the gimbal for its angles as quickly as possible.

Therefore I use the "Handheld Gimbal Information Obtaining" command from the DJI-SDK (CmdID = 0x02).
Reading the answer for the command, it seems that the angles are updated with 5 Hz. Asking with a much higher frequency, I do receive the answer with a higher frequency as well. But the values in the messages are the same (e.g. asking with 20 Hz, I get 4 times the same position, even though the gimbal is constantly moving).

I found something on github on this topic (https://github.com/rileycoyote87/DJI-Ronin-RS2-Log-and-Replay/). Here it is stated, that the information is received in real-time. Looking at the "dji.log", you can see, that there is the same position several times. Which is the same problem as I experience.

Is there any way to work around that and get the position more often? Or is the hardware limited?

Thank you very much!